# Package manager - Triggered Send Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send, package-manager

I'm wondering how to solve the deployment of a lot of "triggered send data extension" with Deployment manager of Marketing Cloud.

The system show me this warning:

Data Extension Template "TriggeredSendDataExtension" must be provisioned in destination account

And if I go ahead with the deployment, I'm expcted that somewhere it request me to put the template ID or Externalkey but it's never heppends, and **it create the Data Extension but the without using "TriggeredSendDataExtension" as template** and it's useless because I can't use it in the Triggers Definition.

Have someone find some workaroud for it? Maybe by changing something in the Deployment JSONS?

Thank you, Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert message:

> Data Extension Template "TriggeredSendDataExtension" must be provisioned in destination account

is simply a warning but when the package is deployed to an other BU/Account the Data Extension is still available as `TriggeredSendDataExtension` and should be used as target DE for Triggered Send and also for Transactional Messaging.

:)